# Uboot driver probe

Tags: driver, powerpc, u-boot

I am working on a project which was already built by 3 people. THey have made the Freertos port on P4080 using uboot.

Now the question is, I have very less knowledge of uboot. So, how can I find/porbe which uart driver is Uboot using to connect with minicom?

I searched in the uboot directory, there were several drivers. I am sure, in some script/folder it must be defined about which driver to use for uart on P4080 ? How and where can I find it ?

Thanks you.

Sumanth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider to look the file `u-boot_directory/include/configs/*yourboard*.h`

You normally will find some `#define` used for serial configuration.

Comment: thank you Cyril :) Will check on it, after returning from Christmas, merry christmas to you too :)